Combine dictionaries with same key using JSONata
I am trying to combine the information from two dictionaries into one. I have a JSON like this:
{
 "First": {
          "example1": [
            {
              "key": "A",
              "value_1": 5
            },
            {
              "key": "B",
              "value_1": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "C",
              "value_1": 6
            },
            {
              "key": "D",
              "value_1": 8
            },
            {
              "key": "E",
              "value_1": 2
            }
         ]
 },
 "Second":{
          "example2": [
            {
              "key": "A",
              "value_2": 2
            },
            {
              "key": "B",
              "value_2": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "C",
              "value_2": 1
            }
         ]
 }
}

What I'm trying to get is one JSON with the same key and the two different values. Ideally if there are no values for value_2, then it should just be 0. Something like this:
{
 "Result":[
            {
              "key": "A",
              "value_1": 5,
              "value_2": 2

            },
            {
              "key": "B",
              "value_1": 1,
              "value_2": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "C",
              "value_1": 1,
              "value_2": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "D",
              "value_1": 8,
              "value_2": 0
            },
            {
              "key": "E",
              "value_1": 2,
              "value_2": 0
            }
         ]
 }


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try:
(*.*{key: {
    'key': $distinct(key),
    'value_1': value_1, 
    'value_2': [value_2, 0][0]
    }})
.{'Result': *}

See https://try.jsonata.org/kObVLMPnj
